# how Drupal CSS URL errors could be fixed?

Tags: css, drupal

I've just got a fresh Drupal 6 install. The CSS didn't work. Then I realized that a "?U" was appended, and Drupal couldn't find it. Does anyone know where to unset this?

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/node/node.css?U" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/admin.css?U" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/defaults.css?U" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/system.css?U" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/system/system-menus.css?U" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/modules/user/user.css?U" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/bluemarine/style.css?U" />
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the source of your problem? The ?U should have no effect. What web server are you running? A strange server configuration might make the ?U significant.

Answer (score 5):

the ?U (or really any alphabet) is just a method drupal uses to cache information. it has no relevance to the location of the file (ie, node.css and node.css?U is in the same location to drupal).

it sounds like you may have a different issue. perhaps you enabled your cache and moved things around? you may need to clear your cache. or, if you've modified your install variables perhaps you're picking up the wrong base path or something. it's hard to tell the exact issue based on the limited information given.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Its because of the cache. I configured nginx to serve css files directly. But after I modified the configuration, it works fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Drupal into a sub-directory?  Like:

```
http://domain.com/drupal
```

This would certainly cause the problems you speak of, though Drupal should have properly accommodated for that.